# Starting USSD session after a call

Tags: ussd

How can I initiate a ussd session from within a call to a phone number in my ivr?
For example, if a user calls a number and it is answered with a recording, when the call is ended I want to display on the caller's handset (using ussd) a PIN code.
I know this sort of mechanism should be possible as I have tried a demo on site globalussd.com